# I am trying to print the length of last word in the string - but when I run the below code I see it is going in infinite loop. What am i missing here?

Tags: python-3.x

print the length of the last word in the string.

```py
s = "   fly me   to   the moon  "

s1 = s.split(' ')

length = len(s1) - 1

while(length < len(s1)):

    if s1[length] == ' ':
        length-=1
    else:
        print(len(s1[-1]))
```

I was expecting it would print - 4 - but it is going in infinite loop

Comment: There is a difference between `s.split(' ')` and `s.split()`. Try them in the Python interpreter to see for your self. Also, learn how to use a debugger such as `pdb` to walk through your code.

Answer (score 1):

since you're splitting by every space character, there won't be any space character string in your `s1` list.
so, the else condition will be executed where you're just printing the length of the string(which is 0).

you don't have a break condition in your else block so it goes into infinite loop.

i'd suggest first trimming the string to solve the problem, and return when your condition is met.